# Difference of current time and past time in minutes?

Tags: java, date, time

I want to calculate the difference of saved time and the current time in minutes. This is how i tried.

```
public static boolean on_pause() {
    current_date = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    long diffInMillisec = current_date.getTime() - saved_date.getTime();
    long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMillisec);
    difference = diffInSec % 60;
    diffInSec /= 60;

    if (difference <= 3) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}

public static void on_resume() {

    saved_date = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

The line current_date.getTime() and saved_date.getTime() showing error(method getTime() is undefined for the String type). Please help me out.

Comment: Do not use DateFormat at all.  Do not use Strings at all.  Math is performed on numbers, not formatted strings.  You don't even need the Calendar class.  `System.currentTimeMills()` returns the current time in milliseconds.  Save that long value, subtract it from the current time, and convert to minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do this

```
public static boolean on_pause() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - saved_date > 3 * 60 * 1000;
}

public static void on_resume() {
    saved_date = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

This is a difference of 180 seconds.  If you compare just the minutes you could be 239 seconds after and still not consider this to be more than 3 minutes, as you ignore the number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
current_date = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
        Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

returns the current time (string).
So then When you try `current_date.getTime()` you are trying to get the time from a string.
Do this (untested but it should work):

```
Calendar current_date  = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then you should call current_date.getTime(), and parse the answer to int/long/double. Do the same for saved_date.

Check this out too: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Try, and write for further help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get the actual date/time

use

```
Time current_date  = new Time();
current_date.setToNow();
```

and

```
Time saved_date = = new Time();
saved_date.setToNow();
```

the rest of the code looks ok to me